# fabric is not getting Django environment

Tags: python, django, linux, virtualenv, fabric

I have a fabric file in my local system which I am using to deploy a code in remote server ( in a virtualenv ) and want to test it. The method definition is like below.

```
    def test_deploy(gitid = '930bfc4'):
        # manually put the commit id at the end
        path = '/tmp/testapp/app1/source/demo4'
        with cd(path):
            commit_id = 'git fetch https://myaccount@github.org/myaccount/demo4.git/heads/master:https://myaccount@github.org/myaccount/demo4.git/remotes/origin/master/'+gitid
            # change the settings.py file and update the database
            run (commit_id)
            run ('cat .git/FETCH_HEAD')

        path1 = '/tmp/testvehic/vehic'
        with cd(path1):
            run ('pwd')
            env.activate = 'source /tmp/testapp/app1/bin/activate'
            run ('python /tmp/testapp/app1/source/demo4/manage.py test')`
```

It is showing that

> ImportError: No module named django.core.management

After some search in Google I came to know that it is not actually locating my django environment.
My virtual environment path is `/tmp/testapp/app1`
And the source code are in `/tmp/testapp/app1/source/app1/`
When I am running the command `python manage.py test` in server terminal its working fine. How can I test that through fabric?

Comment: Stop tying to activate things, too many people get it wrong, do this instead: `/tmp/testvehic/vehic/bin/python /tmp/testapp/app1/source/demo4/manage.py test` its guaranteed to not fail; no one will look at the code and be confused by it; easier to debug; NOTHING BUT WINS!! :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from the below link

http://nurupoga.org/articles/deployment-with-fabric-and-virtualenv/

my code snippet now looks like this

```
VENV_DIR = '/home/rootuser/testvehic/vehic'
PROJECT_DIR = '/home/rootuser/testvehic/vehic/source/cabsdemo4'

@contextmanager
def source_virtualenv():
    with prefix('source ' + os.path.join(VENV_DIR, 'bin/activate')):
        yield
def test_deploy(gitid = '930bfc4'):
    # manually put the commit id at the end
    path = '/tmp/testapp/app1/source/demo4'
    with cd(path):
        commit_id = 'git fetch https://myaccount@github.org/myaccount/demo4.git/heads/master:https://myaccount@github.org/myaccount/demo4.git/remotes/origin/master/'+gitid
        # change the settings.py file and update the database
        run (commit_id)
        run ('cat .git/FETCH_HEAD')
    with settings(warn_only=True):
        with cd(PROJECT_DIR):
            with source_virtualenv():
                run('pip install -r requirements.txt')
                run('python manage.py test')
```